# tmux - shared server not in /tmp?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to use `tmux` on an enterprise cluster that dumps `/tmp` regularly.  I want to store the sockets for a shared project in `/proj/foo/shells`.  I can create a session with `tmux -S /proj/foo/shells/bar new -s nameOfTheSession`, but these do not show up in `tmux ls`, and I cannot now figure out how to administrate them?  Each time I connect with `tmux -S /proj/foo/shells/bar` a new session is created, which I can kill with `ctrl+b x`, but now I'm just up to `[5]`.

How do I use tmux this way?  I want `ls` to work properly, and the shells/sessions to behave in a way that I could do `tmux a bar` and get back into `/proj/foo/shells/bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Every* command has to be given the `-S` option to tell it which (alternate) socket to use.

```
$ tmux -S /proj/new/shells/bar new -s nameOfTheSession
$ tmux -S /proj/new/shells/bar ls
```

The command `tmux -S /proj/foo/shells/bar` does not somehow make every future call to `tmux` use the given path; it just sends the default command `new-session` to the server at the given path.

It seems that you don't care what the name of the actual socket is, as long as it is stored under `/proj/foo/shells`. In that case, just set `TMUX_TMPDIR` to your environment:

```
export TMUX_TMPDIR=/proj/foo/shells
```

Now any time you run `tmux`, it will default to a server available at `/proj/foo/shells/default`. You can still use the `-L` option to specify a server name other than `default` (such as `-L bar` to use the server `/proj/foo/shells/bar` instead).